# Why does atmospheric drag speed up satellites?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, atmospheric-science, drag, satellites

I've read that old satellites slowly lose altitude when encountering the very thin atmosphere, and strangely enough they speed up. My theory is that the work done by the drag force is insignificant in comparison to the whole energy of the orbiter, $$ E = -\frac{GmM}{2r} $$ so it essentially pushes it to a lower orbit while mostly conserving the total energy. This would explain why it speeds up, but I can't quite visualize how a force that acts tangentially to the path can produce radial deviations .

Comment: See: [Work, Energy and the “Satellite Drag Paradox”](https://physicsfromplanetearth.wordpress.com/2017/02/13/work-energy-and-the-satellite-drag-paradox/)

Answer (score 3):

> I can't quite visualize how a force that acts tangentially to the path can produce radial deviations.

Consider a satellite orbiting the earth on a circular orbit.
If there would be no air drag, then
the attractive gravitational force ($F_g=-\frac{GMm}{r}$) and
the repulsive centrifugal force ($F_c=mr\dot{\phi}^2$) would perfectly balance.
And hence the radius $r$ stays constant, giving a circular orbit.

Now add some air drag. The drag force is acting horizontally.
That means that the angular speed ($\dot{\phi}$), and hence
the centrifugal force ($F_c=mr\dot{\phi}^2$) will decrease.
This destroys the balance between centrifugal force
and gravitational force, so that there is now a small
net force pointing down towards the earth.

Comment: So radial velocity increases?

Comment: @RobertSzili  well, yeah,  :-) , that's why things fall out of the sky and burn or crash